# Error creating game objects in c++

Tags: c++

I have been working in a zombie arcade game, I am experimenting an strange problem. I created a class called GameObject and a class called Human that inherits from GameOBject, then I declared two more called; Zombie and Player. The problem is that when I create two or more characters (instances) of this four classes the game stops working, I detected that in the classes Zombie and Player the problem only occurs when I call the method update (only these classes use it). This method is supposed to control the activities of each character.
The graphics and animated sprites are managed separately from the character, they (the characters) only call some methods to control the sprite update, those orders are processed when updating the screen.

I just want you to tell me what is happening, I think the problem is in the update method of the classes Zombie and Player.

The project is divided in different files.

I don't think this matters but I am using CodeBlocks and tdm-gcc.

main.cpp:

```
#include "game_classes.h"

bool working = true, redraw = true;

int main(){

    init_game_classes();

    Player player(200, 200);

    std::vector<Zombie *> zombie_list;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 2; i++){

        Zombie *zombie = new Zombie(i * 100, 12, &player);
        zombie_list.push_back(zombie);

    }

    while(working){

        input();

        if(event.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER){//main loop

            player.update();

            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < zombie_list.size(); i++){

                zombie_list[i]->update();

            }

            redraw = true;

        }

        else if(event.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE){

            working = false;

        }

        if(redraw and al_is_event_queue_empty(event_queue)){//updating display

            update_animated_models();
            blit_models();
            update_display();
            redraw = false;

        }

    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < zombie_list.size(); i++)
        delete zombie_list[i];

    quit();
    return 0;

}
```

render.h:

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_image.h>

int global_ticks_per_frame = 0;

ALLEGRO_BITMAP *map_background = NULL;

class Model;

std::vector<Model *> model_list;

class Model{

protected:

    int x = 0, y = 0, width, height;
    int source_x = 0, source_y = 0, source_width, source_height;

public:

    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *sheet = NULL;
    bool hide = false;
    int flags = 0;

    Model(const char *path, int width, int height){

        this->sheet = al_load_bitmap(path);
        al_convert_mask_to_alpha(this->sheet, al_map_rgb(255, 0, 255));

        this->source_width = al_get_bitmap_width(this->sheet);
        this->source_height = al_get_bitmap_height(this->sheet);

        this->width = width;
        this->height = height;

        model_list.insert(model_list.begin(), this);

    }

    Model(ALLEGRO_BITMAP *image, int width, int height){

        this->sheet = image;
        al_convert_mask_to_alpha(this->sheet, al_map_rgb(255, 0, 255));

        this->source_width = al_get_bitmap_width(this->sheet);
        this->source_height = al_get_bitmap_height(this->sheet);

        this->width = width;
        this->height = height;

        model_list.insert(model_list.begin(), this);

    }

    ~Model(){

        al_destroy_bitmap(this->sheet);
        model_list.erase(model_list.begin() + this->index());

    }

    void show(){

        if(not this->hide){

            al_draw_scaled_bitmap(this->sheet, this->source_x, this->source_y, this->source_width, this->source_height, x, y, width, height, this->flags);

        }

    }

    void set_x(int x){

        this->x = x;

    }

    unsigned int index(){

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < model_list.size(); i++){

            if(model_list[i] == this)
                return i;

        }

    }

    bool set_y(int y){

        this->y = y;
        model_list.erase(model_list.begin() + this->index());
        int this_relative_y = this->y + this->height;

        unsigned int i = 0;

        while(i < model_list.size()){

            int from_list_relative_y = model_list[i]->y + model_list[i]->height;

            if(this_relative_y < from_list_relative_y){

                model_list.insert(model_list.begin() + i, this);
                return false;

            }

            i += 1;

        }

        model_list.push_back(this);
        return false;

    }

    int get_y(){

        return this->y;

    }

    int get_x(){

        return this->x;

    }

    unsigned int get_width(){

        return this->width;

    }

    unsigned int get_height(){

        return this->height;

    }

};

void blit_models(){

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < model_list.size(); i++)
        model_list[i]->show();

}

class AnimatedModel;

std::vector<AnimatedModel *> animated_model_list;

class AnimatedModel : public Model{

private:

    unsigned int ticks_per_frame, ticks_counter = 0;
    unsigned int current_frame = 0, frame_count;

public:

    bool stop = false;

    void set_speed(unsigned int new_speed){

        this->ticks_per_frame = new_speed;

    }

    AnimatedModel(const char *path, unsigned int frames, unsigned int ticks_per_frame, int width, int height) : Model(path, width, height){

        this->ticks_per_frame = ticks_per_frame;
        this->frame_count = frames;
        this->source_width /= frames;

        animated_model_list.push_back(this);

    }

    AnimatedModel(ALLEGRO_BITMAP *image, unsigned int frames, unsigned int ticks_per_frame, int width, int height) : Model(image, width, height){

        this->ticks_per_frame = ticks_per_frame;
        this->frame_count = frames;
        this->source_width /= frames;

        animated_model_list.push_back(this);

    }

    ~AnimatedModel(){

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < animated_model_list.size(); i++){

            if(animated_model_list[i] == this){

                animated_model_list.erase(animated_model_list.begin() + i);

            }

        }

    }

    void fix_sheet_looking(){

        if(not this->stop)
            this->source_x = this->current_frame*this->source_width;

    }

    void play(){

        if(this->ticks_counter >= this->ticks_per_frame + global_ticks_per_frame){

            this->current_frame += 1;

            if(this->current_frame >= this->frame_count)
                this->current_frame = 0;

            this->ticks_counter = 0;

        }

        else{

            this->ticks_counter += 1;

        }

    }

    void update(){

        if(not this->stop){

            this->play();
            this->fix_sheet_looking();

        }

    }

    void set_frame(unsigned int i){

        this->current_frame = i;

    }

    unsigned int get_frame(){

        return this->current_frame;

    }

};

void update_animated_models(){

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < animated_model_list.size(); i++)
        animated_model_list[i]->update();

}
```

game_classes.h:

```
#include "render.h"
#include "touch.h"
#include "window_control.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

ALLEGRO_BITMAP *zombie_sprite = NULL;
ALLEGRO_BITMAP *human_sprite = NULL;

void init_game_classes(){

    init_window_control();

    zombie_sprite = al_load_bitmap("textures/zombie/sprite.png");
    human_sprite = al_load_bitmap("textures/human/sprite.png");

}

int control_key_up = ALLEGRO_KEY_UP, control_key_down = ALLEGRO_KEY_DOWN, control_key_right = ALLEGRO_KEY_RIGHT, control_key_left = ALLEGRO_KEY_LEFT;
int control_key_run = ALLEGRO_KEY_Z;

HitBoxList character_body_reg;
HitBoxList item_body_reg;

class GameObjec{

protected:

    unsigned int walking_speed;
    HitBoxList *last_coll_test = NULL;
    int last_x, last_y;
    int body_high;
    int left_distance;

public:

    HitBox *body = NULL;
    AnimatedModel *sprite = NULL;

    void set_x(int x){

        this->sprite->set_x(x);
        this->last_x = this->body->x;
        this->body->x = x + this->left_distance;

    }

    void set_y(int y){

        this->sprite->set_y(y);
        this->last_y = this->body->y;
        this->body->y = y + this->body_high;

    }

    int get_x(){

        return this->sprite->get_x();

    }

    int get_y(){

        return this->sprite->get_y();

    }

    void slide_x(short int direction){

        character_body_reg.pop(this->body);
        this->last_coll_test = this->body->slide_x(this->walking_speed*direction, &character_body_reg);
        character_body_reg.push(this->body);

        this->set_x(this->body->x - this->left_distance);

    }

    void slide_y(short int direction){

        character_body_reg.pop(this->body);
        this->last_coll_test = this->body->slide_y(this->walking_speed*direction, &character_body_reg);
        character_body_reg.push(this->body);

        this->set_y(this->body->y - this->body_high);

    }

    void show_hitbox(){

        al_draw_rectangle(this->body->x, this->body->y, this->body->x + this->body->width, this->body->y + this->body->height, al_map_rgb(255, 0, 0), 1);

    }

    GameObjec(int x, int y, unsigned int walking_speed, const char *sprite_image_path, int frames, int ticks_per_frame, int sprite_width, int sprite_height, int body_high, int body_len){

        this->walking_speed = walking_speed;
        this->body_high = body_high;

        this->sprite = new AnimatedModel(sprite_image_path, frames, ticks_per_frame, sprite_width, sprite_height);

        this->left_distance = (this->sprite->get_width() - body_len)/2;

        this->body = new HitBox;

        this->sprite->set_x(x);
        this->sprite->set_y(y);

        this->body->width = body_len;
        this->body->height = this->sprite->get_height() - this->body_high;
        this->body->x = x + left_distance;
        this->body->y = y + this->body_high;

        this->last_x = this->body->x;
        this->last_y = this->body->y;

        character_body_reg.push(this->body);

    }

    ~GameObjec(){

        delete this->sprite;
        character_body_reg.pop(this->body);
        delete this->body;

    }

    void draw_hitbox(){

        al_draw_rectangle(this->body->x, this->body->y, this->body->x + this->body->width, this->body->y + this->body->height, al_map_rgb(255, 0, 0), 0);

    }

};

class Human : public GameObjec{

protected:

    bool walking = false;

public:

    Human(int x, int y, const char *sprite_image_path) : GameObjec(x, y, 2, sprite_image_path, 2, 7, 64, 80, 60, 32){}

    ~Human(){}

    void walk_down(){

        this->slide_y(1);
        this->sprite->stop = false;
        this->walking = true;

    }

    void walk_up(){

        this->slide_y(-1);
        this->sprite->stop = false;
        this->walking = true;

    }

    void walk_right(){

        this->slide_x(1);
        this->sprite->stop = false;
        this->sprite->flags = 0;
        this->walking = true;

    }

    void walk_left(){

        this->slide_x(-1);
        this->sprite->stop = false;
        this->sprite->flags = ALLEGRO_FLIP_HORIZONTAL;
        this->walking = true;

    }

};

class Player : public Human{

public:

    Player(int x, int y) : Human(x, y, "textures/human/sprite.png"){
    }

    void control(){

        if(get_key(control_key_down))
            this->walk_down();

        else if(get_key(control_key_up))
            this->walk_up();

        if(get_key(control_key_right))
            this->walk_right();

        else if(get_key(control_key_left))
            this->walk_left();

        if(not this->walking){

            this->sprite->set_frame(0);
            this->sprite->fix_sheet_looking();
            this->sprite->stop = true;

        }

        if(this->last_x == this->body->x and this->last_y == this->body->y)
            this->walking = false;

    }

    void update(){

        this->control();

    }

};

class Zombie : public Human{

private:

    //Player *to_kill;
    int to_kill_x, to_kill_y;
    unsigned int walk_ticks_counter = 0, follow_ticks_counter = 0;

public:

    Player *to_kill;

    void fix_to_kill_position(){

        if(this->to_kill){

            this->to_kill_x = this->to_kill->body->x;
            this->to_kill_y = this->to_kill->body->y;

        }

        else{

            this->to_kill_x = this->body->x;
            this->to_kill_y = this->body->y;

        }

    }

    Zombie(int x, int y, Player *to_kill) : Human(x, y, "textures/zombie/sprite.png"){

        this->sprite->set_speed(23);
        this->walking_speed = 1;
        this->to_kill = to_kill;

        this->fix_to_kill_position();

    }

   void control(){

        if(this->body->y < to_kill_y)
            this->walk_down();

        else if(this->body->y > to_kill_y)
            this->walk_up();

        if(this->body->x < to_kill_x)
            this->walk_right();

        else if(this->body->x > to_kill_x)
            this->walk_left();

        if(not this->walking){

            this->sprite->set_frame(0);
            this->sprite->fix_sheet_looking();
            this->sprite->stop = true;

        }

    }

    void update(){

        if(this->follow_ticks_counter == 78){

            this->fix_to_kill_position();
            this->follow_ticks_counter = 0;

        }

        else{

            this->follow_ticks_counter += 1;
        }

        if(this->walk_ticks_counter == 2){

            this->control();
            this->walk_ticks_counter = 0;

        }

        else{

            this->walk_ticks_counter += 1;
        }

        if(this->last_x == this->body->x and this->last_y == this->body->y)
            this->walking = false;

    }

};
```

Comment: `ctrl+F new` You probably have [rule of 0/3/5](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) violations, stop using `new` and `delete` and switch to smart pointers.

Comment: What is a smart pointer?

Comment: [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

Comment: googled it one minute ago to know what are you talking about. Couldn't you find any logical error in my code?

Comment: None of your base classes have virtual destructors, this may well be what is causing your issue.

Comment: Ok  user657267, I will try adding it, but I have to say that there is no problem when loading hundreds of animated sprites, the problem only appears when there are two or more characters. If your theory is right, why the problem happens before destroying any object, it happens at the beginning of the execution.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger if you'd rather not receive speculative solutions.

Comment: I didn't say that I would rather not receive any of the exposed solutions. I tried declaring virtual destructors and making virtual some methods and it continues crashing.I will try using smart pointers.

Comment: The problem is that unless you provide a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) all you will probably get is guesswork. I can't copy the code above and compile it to help you, there are parts missing, and in any case you should strip it down to a minimal example.

Comment: The smart pointers solved it! thanks.